# Listview, Gridview or something else for single column of scrolling images

Tags: android, listview, gridview

re: example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej--SFh963M

Similar to the above app, I am trying to create a scrolling list of images, like a Listview but with images only. (I also need to set it to fill a set height and width, say 85% of the height, 10% of the width of the screen). Is a one column Griview best? (I have had troubles in the past selecting the image height of a gridview programatically).

Any online tutorials precisely for this you have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no text and only one column of buttons, it seems like I overlooked the obvious answer of using a scrollview of buttons, which is what I will go with. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

If your view is going to have only one element per row, then the best and correct way of implementation is to use a ListView. The GridView should or can be used when there are going to be multiple elements per row. I believe the purpose of ListView satisfies its role for your need.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a ***GridView*** with **uneven rows** similar to how Pinterest looks. Includes own **OnItemClickListener** and **OnItemLongClickListener**, selector, and fixed position restore. Check out this link, there is a library named "**StaggeredGridView**" : https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo